# Clang optimisation breaks code?

Tags: c, optimization, clang, compiler-optimization

I've tried to prepare minimal viable example of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct FECPUFlags {
    uint16_t CF:1; // carry flag
    uint16_t PF:1; // parity flag
    uint16_t AF:1; // adjust flag
    uint16_t ZF:1; // zero flag
    uint16_t SF:1; // sign flag
    uint16_t TF:1; // trap flag
    uint16_t IF:1; // interrupt enable flag
    uint16_t DF:1; // direction flag
    uint16_t OF:1; // overflow flag
} FECPUFlags;

uint16_t fe_cpuflags_16(FECPUFlags cpuRegister) {
    uint16_t result = 0;

    result = result | cpuRegister.CF;
    result = result | (cpuRegister.PF << 2);
    result = result | (cpuRegister.AF << 4);
    result = result | (cpuRegister.ZF << 6);
    result = result | (cpuRegister.SF << 7);
    result = result | (cpuRegister.DF << 10);
    result = result | (cpuRegister.OF << 11);

    return result;
}

int main() {
    FECPUFlags flag;
#define ENUM(F) for(int i=0;i<=1;i++,flag.F=i)

    ENUM(CF) ENUM(PF) ENUM(AF) ENUM(ZF) ENUM(SF) ENUM(DF) ENUM(OF) {
        printf("0x%X\n",fe_cpuflags_16(flag));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

clang version

```
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0
```

Output of the application differs with different optimisation modes. clang -O0 vs clang -O3.

Here is disasm of optimised version

```
_fe_cpuflags_16:
0000000100000d70        pushq   %rbp
0000000100000d71        movq    %rsp, %rbp
0000000100000d74        movl    %edi, %eax
0000000100000d76        andl    $0x1, %eax
0000000100000d79        leal    (%rdi,%rdi), %ecx
0000000100000d7c        andl    $0x4, %ecx
0000000100000d7f        orl     %eax, %ecx
0000000100000d81        leal    (,%rdi,4), %eax
0000000100000d88        andl    $0x10, %eax
0000000100000d8b        orl     %ecx, %eax
0000000100000d8d        shll    $0x3, %edi
0000000100000d90        movl    %edi, %ecx
0000000100000d92        andl    $0x40, %ecx
0000000100000d95        orl     %eax, %ecx
0000000100000d97        movl    %edi, %eax
0000000100000d99        andl    $0x80, %eax
0000000100000d9e        orl     %ecx, %eax
0000000100000da0        movl    %edi, %ecx
0000000100000da2        andl    $0x400, %ecx            ## imm = 0x400
0000000100000da8        orl     %eax, %ecx
0000000100000daa        andl    $0x800, %edi            ## imm = 0x800
0000000100000db0        orl     %ecx, %edi
0000000100000db2        movzwl  %di, %eax
0000000100000db5        popq    %rbp
0000000100000db6        retq
```

Interesting that if I place memset to zero before enumeration – code works OK.

What kind of optimisation may break this code ? Or may be this code is already broken in some way ?

Comment: "optimisation breaks code" - yeah, that's a sure sign of UB.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Just want to understand what am I doing wrong. Enumeration makes sure that all the flags I'm interested in are initialised. Even if I manually initialise TF/IF which are not used – optimised app still gives different results.

Comment: "Enumeration makes sure that all the flags I'm interested in are initialised." - Nope.

Comment: Only TF/IF not initialised. But as I wrote already – prior initialisation of TF/IF doesn't give nothing. But full memset of flags does provides correct results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using your `FECPUFlags flag;` without initializing it.

This is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Anything could happen.

Comment: Enumeration makes sure that every flag that I interested in is initialized

Comment: @AlexanderSmirnov No it doesn't. `for(int i=0;i<=1;i++,flag.F=i)` sets it's value after the loop body is executed. e.g. you set CF only after all the other loops are executed.

Answer (score 3):

You have an uninitialized variable, which is accessed later, so you have undefined behaviour.

```
FECPUFlags flag;
```

Initialization of (some of the) flags happens only in the second execution of the loop:

```
#define ENUM(F) for(int i=0;i<=1;i++,flag.F=i)
                                     ^^^
```